# Tastypie and django project structure

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I am new to Django. I want to include rest api to my project using tastypie framework. I want to know what are best practices of including tastypie in project. I see two options:

1. Separate app where all api related modules are stored (this app will end up rather fat)
2. api folder in every app with api resources for this particular app (not sure that understand how to organize urls in this case)

So what is the best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I prefer the first approach. I create an api folder and then i create subfolders for each separate application. Each folder contains an api.py file for the specific need.

This way it is really simple and clear to support versions in the api and make it more clear. Also in the api folder i keep a urls.py which contains all the apis from the subfolders and it is easier to maintain.

### EXAMPLE

api/

---

```
app1/ api.py
```

---

```
app2/ api.py
```

---

```
urls.py
```

and the urls.py should look a lot like,

```
from tastypie.api import Api

from .app1.api import App1Resource
from .app2.api import App2Resource


api = Api(api_name='myPath')
api.register(App1Resource())
api.register(App2Resource())


urlpatterns = api.urls
```

This is of-course just my personal preference which have helped me over the years to maintain a variety of different apis.
I hope i helped a bit.

Regards,
Michael.